# How to hide command prompt for my Windows Gtk Apps?

Tags: c, gtk, mingw

I am compiling Gtk applications in Windows with MinGW toolchain, but when I run my apps, a command prompt window appears. How can I make this prompt disappear?

Answer (score 14):

Check [this article](http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/cross-gtk/) out.  You have to specify -mwindows at compile time.

Comment: If you change "might have to" to "definitely have to", I'll give you a point. It's the only way to do it (except for hacks).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Meson (>= 0.56.0), you can set `win_subsystem` kwarg to `windows`, in such commands as [`executable()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#executable), [`library()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#executable), and many others.

For instance:

```
executable(
  'app-gui',
  files(['main.cpp']),
  dependencies: [dependency('gtkmm-4.0')],
  include_directories: include_directories('include'),
  win_subsystem: 'windows'
)
```

**Tip:** Meson would only use the option for cross-compilation and not native builds, so no need to check for anything (e.g. [`meson.is_cross_build()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html#introspection-and-system-checks) is unnecessary).