# Compiling GTK-app cmd-windows with backticks

Tags: c, cmd, gtk3, backticks

According to a tutorial on

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html

for making GUI for c-apps the compiling syntax is

```
gcc base.c -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Its all about these **backticksymbols** and seem to be suited for POSIX on linux.

If backticks in this context is not allowed in CMD-windows - is there a workaround for compiling a GTK-app in c easily?

Comment: So you want compile GTK+ in windows?

Comment: @Jayesh - Yes - I forgot to mention that i have already made an app in Eclipse but want to know how to compile in the windows commandshell

Comment: So this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325552/compiling-and-running-gtk-application-on-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try to use for example [GTK+ for Windows (MinGW)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-mingw/). Also see related questions [How to hide command prompt for my Windows Gtk Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281514/how-to-hide-command-prompt-for-my-windows-gtk-apps) and [Help compiling GTK+ on Windows using MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831522/help-compiling-gtk-on-windows-using-mingw).